# My Java game fills the system memory

Tags: java, libgdx

edited.
I am writing my first game using LIBGDX.
The issue I'm having is that the system memory completely fills up and then even the swap file starts to grow.
From what I see, the memory fills pretty evenly. So it is not one level that has a huge increase of memory usage. As the game moves from level 1 to 2 and so on, the memory usage just keeps going up by a similar amount each time.
I have every arraylist that I use, make sure that it is empty before the level will be declared done and move on to the next so I'm not sure if it is possible that references to objects are being kept.
I have each level set as its own state that gets called by a game state manager and the old level gets set to null, which I thought would allow the java garbage collector to free it from memory.  Perhaps this is not happening though.
Basically how can I free up the memory?
Is declaring a state to null, not the proper way to get the java garbage collector to remove it?
Also is it wrong or bad coding design to have each game level as its own state?

Answer (score 1):

You're not giving us much to go on, but I would start by trying to narrow down where this happens. You should be able to find out something like, for example, the memory definitely does not leak in level 24, but does in level 25. Then start by looking more closely at the code for level 25.

Leaked memory in Java means that you're keeping references to objects, even if you don't know you're keeping them. These are probably hidden someplace, like in an array, or possibly in data that you hand over to libGDX.

Do you use the libGDX memory pools? If so, make sure you're calling `free()` on every object you `obtain()`. Mismatched calls can be really tricky to find. Likewise, make sure you call `dispose()` on all the disposables.

The fact that you're allocating *so much memory* gives us a clue as well. This indicates that you should check any allocations that happen in a loop, (this could fit the case of the memory pool leak), or check for typos in an array sizes, etc.

Your IDE should be able to provide you enough debug information that you can track down which variables are holding all the memory, but that can take a bunch of work with the profiler. If you're not familiar with the profiler, it may be faster/easier to do the search yourself.

Comment: I'm not using any libGDX memory pools.  I have gone over my code numerous times and have made many changes to try and track the issue.... some have been pretty drastic, and still the memory fills full.